# How to exit out of javascript forEach loop

Tags: javascript

I am having an object like below.i will loop through the array of objects and check for any object property has `""` value.the following code works very fine, it sets a flag to true,if any of the objects has an `""` empty value,but it doesn't break out of the **obj.forEach** loop it just exists out of the immediate parent for loop only.how to exit out of the **obj.forEach** loop if any of the object property has `""` value

```js
var obj = [
  {
    "fname": "name1",
    "lname": ""
  },
  {
    "fname": "name2",
    "lname": "lname2"
  },
  {
    "fname": "",
    "lname": "lname3"
  }
];
var hasEmptyValue = false
var hasEmptyProperty = obj3.forEach(function(item) {
    for (var key in item) {
        if (item.hasOwnProperty(key) && item[key] == "") {
            saveIt = true;
            break;
        }
        console.log("key->",key,"value ->",item[key]); 
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't, use `for` loop, if you need a breakable loop.

Comment: So how i can achieve it without for loop

Comment: Use `while` loop then.

Comment: or simply use a `return`statement ...

Comment: Ah maybe i didn't understand the question then : i thought he wanted to only stop for one item only

Comment: @Xatyrian i tried return it doesn't work.my question is to exit out of the obj.Foreach loop when the object property is `""`.

Comment: You mean stop iterating over the array or just stop for the current item ?

Comment: @codegeek "So how i can achieve it without for loop" read linked question. There is more specific method for your requirements `obj3.some(item => Object.keys(item).some(key => item[key] == ''))`

Comment: @Xatyrian i have to stop iterating over the array not just the current item.the current solution is exit the loop for particular item

Comment: @Yury Tarabanko can you elaborate little bit

Comment: @codegeek `.forEach` is general iteration method that does something "for each" element in array. It has no notion of stop and is not the best option for your requirements. Since you want to check if **some** element has **some** value that is empty string there is godsend method just for you https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the MDN web docs:

> There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by
>   throwing an exception.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach